# Delphi 6 support for toolbar and menu icons with alpha channel transparency

Tags: delphi, alpha, alphablending, alpha-transparency, delphi-6

We have a legacy application developed in Delphi 6 (yes, I know this is an ancient IDE now), which we are trying to update to look more modern. We have added in a Manifest and now have it using version 6 Windows controls and taking on the Windows Visual Theme (all good).

However, when trying to replace the old 4 bit toolbar and menu icons with True Colour with Alpha Channel (32 bit) transparency we have hit a problem. It appears that Delphi 6 only supports transparency based on the bottom left pixel colour (http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2007/qt/timage_transp.htm) and does not support more modern alpha-blended transparency. This is causing an issue, as all the graphics we have had created are in this format and do not look good when added to the toolbar due to anti-aliasing creating a fringe effect (in the background colour on which they were created, transparent becomes white in this case) around them.

I have been scouring the internet for hours trying to confirm whether or not Delphi 6 does or can be made to support these image formats, but, as Delphi 6 is so old now, I am only finding references to Delphi 7 and above.

Can anyone confirm whether what we are trying to achieve is possible or if there are any workarounds for this apparent limitation? Please note that upgrading to a newer version of Delphi is not an option for this particular project due to limited budget and time.

Comment: You can do this. You need to create the image list handle yourself. And load the images yourself, ideally from resources. Rest assured I used full 32bpp alpha icons in image lists in Delphi 6, no problems.

Comment: As well as the manifest you need Mike Lischke's theme manager code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That is good to hear. Please could you provide a little further guidance on how to do this? It would be most appreciated.

Comment: Mike's theme manager you can find by web search.

Comment: I created my image list like this: `var
  _ToolbarImages: TMyImageList;

function ToolbarImages: TMyImageList;
var
  IconSize: Integer;
begin
  if not Assigned(_ToolbarImages) then begin
    _ToolbarImages := TMyImageList.Create(nil);
    IconSize := IconSizeFromMetric(ICON_SMALL);
    _ToolbarImages.Handle := ImageList_Create(IconSize, IconSize, ILC_COLOR32 or ILC_MASK, 0, _ToolbarImages.AllocBy);
    if not _ToolbarImages.HandleAllocated then begin
      raise EInvalidOperation.Create(SInvalidImageList);
    end;
  end;
  Result := _ToolbarImages;
end;
`

Comment: I added icons like this: `function TMyImageList.AddIconResource(const ResourceName: string): Integer;
var
  Icon: HICON;
begin
  Assert(Width=Height);
  Icon := LoadIconResourceSize(ResourceName, Width);
  if Icon=0 then begin
    RaiseLastOSError;
  end;
  Try
    Result := ImageList_AddIcon(Handle, Icon);
    if Result=-1 then begin
      RaiseLastOSError;
    end;
  Finally
    DestroyIcon(Icon);
  End;
end;
`

Comment: `LoadIconResourceSize` is more involved, but basically it loads a 32 bpp resource.

Comment: See if that gets you going. I'm afraid I don't have time in the next few days to turn this into something polished for you. Sorry.

Comment: No problem. Very grateful for something to point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: `ILC_COLOR32 or ILC_MASK` in `ImageList_Create` is the key. That's what D6 won't do for you.

Comment: My other advice is to explore this in a new test app. Don't try to tack this into the real app until you really know how it all works. And don't expect to see the images at designtime. Settle for loading them up from resources at runtime.

Comment: In my BCB6 apps, I use a 3rd party `TPNGImageList` instead of the standard `TImageList`.  Alphablended/transparent PNGs appear just fine in my toolbars and menus.

Comment: @Remy's suggestion is probably a really good way to go. I implemented this myself because I knew how to do it, but if you don't, and you can find a good third party library that does it well, go for it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for the suggestion. Would you have a link to the third party TPNGImageList component to which you refer? Searching for it only appears to return results for a component for Delphi 7.

Comment: I use the `TPngImageList` component from Thany.org's PngComponents suite ([link on Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20071214214235/http://thany.org/article/32/PngComponents)). There are updated versions floating around. There is a [D2007 version](http://www.torry.net/vcl/packs/other/PNGComponents.zip) on Torry.net, a [D2009-Seattle version](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/26127) on CodeCentral, and even [one on GoogleCode](https://code.google.com/p/cubicexplorer/downloads/detail?name=PngComponents.zip) that includes D6 packages. You might have to mix-and-match sources.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you! I have been struggling to find the original, as thany.org seems to have changed ownership and all links seemed to be pointing to components that do not support anything below Delphi 7 (which has been a common problem whilst trying to find a solution to this).