# Delphi 6 TDateTimePicker Windows Visual Theme support via Manifest

Tags: delphi, delphi-6

As per my previous question ([Delphi 6 support for toolbar and menu icons with alpha channel transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33291064/delphi-6-support-for-toolbar-and-menu-icons-with-alpha-channel-transparency)), we are updating a legacy application developed in Delphi 6 to support Windows Visual Themes by including a Manifest. This has worked well and we have the majority of controls adopting the Windows visual theme correctly.

However, we do have a problem with TDateTimePicker behaving in a slightly odd manner. We have the form colour set to white (RGB 255/255/255) and the input box for TDateTimePicker is not visible on the form until it is clicked into and has an entry in it. Please see screenshots below:

[image: Invisible when not selected]

[image: Visible when selected]

Changing the form colour to grey, we can see that the box is there when not selected, it just has no border drawn around it:

[image: Visible on grey background]

We have been unable to find a property that will change this behaviour. Can anyone shed some light on why this might be occurring, what property needs to be changed, or another method we could possibly use to resolve it?

Comment: You're using Mike Lischke's theme manager?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Not yet, we still have to implement. Will this correct this?

Comment: I don't know. I don't think it's worth making any judgements at all until you have the theme manager code integrated. You are wasting your time until you've done that, in my view. You need that code, it fixes lots of issues. So add it, and then review.

Comment: http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/controls/windows-xp-theme-manager

Comment: Thanks. We will implement this first and then reassess.

Comment: I'm not saying that it will deal with date time picker controls. I cannot see any mention of that control specifically. But there may be issues with parent controls and so on that impact on this. Anyway, I think the bottom line is that you have to include this code to get anywhere.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, I could not see any specific mention of that control either, hence the question. Seems like it is fairly essential for proper Visual Theme support then.

Comment: I find it a little difficult to understand how all of the hours you're putting in to update the UI using an antiquated version of the IDE is more cost-effective than just upgrading your Delphi version and being done with it.

Comment: @KenWhite I have been told that the barrier (other than the upgrade cost) to doing this is mainly due to the use of a number of old third party components from companies that are long since out of business and are no longer supported. Apparently, it would require quite a major rewrite of the code. The objective is to simply freshen up the GUI. Please note that I am not the application developer, I am just helping manage the project.

Comment: Freshen up the GUI is quite viable with Delphi 6. Probably a good move if you otherwise aren't making significant devlopments.